# Do I need to put semicolon at the end of my Cypher query?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb

When I write a Cypher query in `mgconsole` my query will not run unless I put semicolon at the end of the query. In Memgraph Lab I don't need to put a semicolon and my query runs as it should.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cypher queries can span through multiple lines and should end with a semi-colon as it concludes your input.